# Partial range query using Kafka Streams, RocksDB and Avro schema

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have an avro schema named `CompositeKey` with fields of `<userId: int, attribute: string>`. Another avro schema named `SimpleValue`.

Using Kafka Streams, I put them into a KeyValueStore using Avro serializer/deserializers.

```
myKeyValueStore.put(myCompositeKey, mySimpleValue);
```

Later on, using interactive queries I can `get` `userId, attribute` pairs one by one. But I'd like to also get all `attributes` belonging to a single `userId`. When I use,

```
store.range(
    new CompositeKey(userID, lowestPossibleAttribute), 
    new CompositeKey(userID, highestPossibleAttribute))
```

it does not return all attributes. I guess that is caused because underlying RocksDB sorts them like byte arrays and avro serialization format messes with that.

Is there a way to do this partial range query using Avro in RocksDB? Otherwise I will have to store them with generated strings from Avro schema in the format of `"<userId>+<attribute>"`.

Comment: You cross-posted your question to Confluent's mailing list (FYI other readers: Confluent is the main vendor for all things Apache Kafka), and you have already received first feedback: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/confluent-platform/QQ5TMJzjx20/ZmW3TVfBBwAJ